# Error when trying to install GPGME

Tags: gcc, make, gnupg, c, makefile

I'm trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15971087) descrption for installing GnuPG interface on Ubuntu. The output of `./configure` is

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/batzinger/Downloads/gpgme-1.8.0':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

The build-essential package is already installed. And there seems to be no other solution on the internet. 
Any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you install compiler then immediately tried to compile app?

Comment: Yep. I tried to compile immediately and I tried again after reboot and purging and reinstalling build-essential, gcc and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Ubuntu, you should be fine just installing some packets from the repository. `php-gnupg` has GPGME's `libgpgme11` package as dependency. So instead of compiling GPGME on your own, simply install the required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gnupg
```

This also means you will get updates for GPGME and the PHP library together with your operating system, and will not have to care about them manually.